# IBM Cloud NLU service creation does not allow me to pick space/org

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-nlu

I am working through the tutorial on how to use the Java SDK with NLU service. Here: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/how-to-use-watson-developer-java-sdk-to-call-watson-nlu-service/#create-the-nlu-service the tutorial says to create an NLU service. When I try to do this, it does not allow me to assign this service to a specific org or space, as is show in that tutorial image.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA48M.png) image shows what I see when trying to create the NLU service instance. I have tried every region to see if it allows me to change space or org, but no luck. It just shows that all I can pick from is the Default resource group.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne77j.png) image shows that I do in fact have an organization, as well as a space associated with that organization.

Is assigning the NLU service to a org/space necessary? I have attempted to continue through the tutorial without this, but it seems to be affecting the next steps in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to assign your NLU service to a cloud foundry org/space.

In November 2017, IBM Cloud added support for resource groups. This enables you to group resources across regions and to manage access to those resources based on their resource groups.  For more information on resource group management, please visit the [docs here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/resources/resourcegroups.html#rgs).

Also, if you have a service or app under a Cloud Foundry space and org, you can easily migrate it to a resource group following the instructions [mentioned here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/resources/instance_migration.html#migrate)

Comment: I would upvote you but this is a new account and I don't have enough reputation to do so. I believe the problem I was having later in the tutorial is actually unrelated to the spaces now that I know it is not necessary. Thank you for your help!